# MySQL delete from multiple tables with one variable

Tags: mysql

I want to delete three rows, from three separate tables. Here is my query, but it doesnt seem to work.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `DB`.`deleteArticle` (IN x INT)
BEGIN

DELETE FROM articles
where article_id=x;

DELETE FROM AUTHORS
where submission_id = select submission_id from article_files where article_id=X;

DELETE FROM article_files
where article_id=X;

END
```

Comment: "it doesnt seem to work" what doesnt work ? errors ? what did you expect it to delete ? care to show some data from your table ?

Comment: You have a typo in the last block (DLETE should be DELETE)\

Comment: @dragon112 sorry it was a type while typing the query.

Comment: Do you have any foreign key constraints in place? Eg I'd expect you need to delete from article_files before articles (or cascade delete from parent to child)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this one

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `DB`.`deleteArticle` (IN x INT)
BEGIN

DELETE FROM articles
WHERE article_id=x;

DELETE FROM AUTHORS
WHERE submission_id IN (SELECT submission_id FROM article_files WHERE article_id=X);

DELETE FROM article_files
WHERE article_id=X;

END
```